# Xamarin ios submission error when submitting adhoc distribution to TestFlight

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, app-store, testflight

So i have been trying to get past the following error after submitting my app to Apple TestFight:

```
Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app. Please correct the following 
issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use 
WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more 
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
```

Here is what i have tried:

1. Verified i am using xamarin >4.5
2. Verified i am using Visual Studio >Studio 16.4.3
3. Verified i am using Xamarin.iOS >Xamarin.iOS 13.10.0.17
4. I have iOS build same as what Microsoft recommends(see screenshot)
   [image]
5. I verified using mtouch arg --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView that build output does not have any reference to UIWebView.
6. My solution does not contain the text "UIWebView"

This issue seems to be quite a popular one since i found lots of references to same problem but none of the fixes worked for me. I did all the steps [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/)

Does anyone have any advice on what i should be looking for other than submitting a ticket with Apple whish is obviously a last resort.

I have now also performed following:

1. Renaming .ipa file to .zip and extracting.
2. Performed following search on contents - grep -r UIWebView .
3. Got following results
   ./[app name].iOS matches

I am not sure what to do with that information?

Now in visual studio i add these additional mtouch args:

```
-warnaserror:1502 -warnaserror:1503
```

This produced following:

```
One or more reference(s) to type 'UIKit.UIWebView' already exists inside 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' before linking arnBooking.iOS
```

Not sure how to find where this is at?

Comment: Hi, do you have a check with the project whether also contains code of using `UIWebView`? You need to remove all of them used in anywhere.

Comment: Yes there are no references to UIWebView. I stated that clearly in my question

Comment: Okey, if you have configured that, do you clean the project and rebuild to check whehter it works?

Comment: Yes i have cleaned app several times along with restarting both windows and mac machines. On top of cleaning i delete the bin and obj folders manually

Comment: Okey, if good ideas will update here later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here turned out to be the HockeySDK.Xamarin package i was using which is apparently now deprecated. Upon removing this dependency and replacing with AppCenter the submission was approved. I figured this out by sheer luck so i am concerned about being in a hopeless place again in future where apple denies my submission with little to no clue of how i can fix.